# Naked domain subdirectories/files redirect to root www

Tags: redirects, dns, 301-redirect, domain-registrar

I have a 301 Redirect setup for my naked domain (something.com) to redirect to the www subdomain (www.something.com). However, I'm running into an issue I didn't foresee: when someone links to, for example, something.com/thisthing.html, it redirects to www.something.com/ instead of www.something.com/thisthing.html, which is what I want. Is there any way to achieve this effect? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set as below in your .htaccess file. This should help.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something.com$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.something\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```